# Suppress Code Analysis message CA1704 for HbA1c, Multi, Num, Exp using CustomDictionary.xml

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, static-analysis

I use CustomDictionary.xml to Suppress Code Analysis warning CA1704.
This works in almost all cases except for few like below

1. 'Exp' in type name
   'SelectCalMicroalbuminCreatinineCartridgeLotNumByExpDateCmd'.
2. Remove the underscores from member name
   'TransmissionStatus.NOTSENT_COMMSOFF'
3. Correct the casing of 'c' in member name
   'Configuration.ResetHbA1cReferenceRange()' by changing it to 'C'.
   **the most annoying one is this one** since we have around 2000 "HbA1c" words in solution
4. "Multi", "Sum" "Idx".

They are present in CustomDictionary.xml in  section but Code Analysis looks like do not see them.
I have added **"HbA1c"** in discrete exceptions, that doesn't help.